# How to remove threaded crank arm

Tags: maintenance, crankset, bottom-bracket

I'm trying to service my son's bike that was left outside over the winter. I'm not sure what type of cranks and bottom bracket I have.

The crank arms seem to be threaded and the bottom bracket looks like there is a cup that could be hiding some bearing.

Has anyone seem anything like this before?

How can I remove the arm and the bottom bracket for servicing?

[image: close-up of non-drive side of bottom bracket]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE! Does this answer your question? [What tool should I be using on this bottom bracket?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86808/what-tool-should-i-be-using-on-this-bottom-bracket)

Comment: Ah ok so this is a one piece crank arm I think

Comment: Exactly sReall. The answer to the question I linked should cover everything you need to service it. It also includes a link to the very good Park Tool repair article about one-piece cransket. Happy fixing!